# Apache Jena - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory

Tags: java, stream, jena

I am trying this tutorial and want to run the following code:

```
public class test extends Object {
    // some definitions
    static String personURI    = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
    static String fullName     = "John Smith";

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        // create an empty model
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        // create the resource
        Resource johnSmith = model.createResource(personURI);

        // add the property
        johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
    }

}
```

These are my project settings:

[image]

However, I am getting an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelFactory : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.dataGenerator.test.test.main(test.java:15)


Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your answer!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java version at compile time is higher than the java version at runtime. Major version 51 is Java 7 make sure your runtime environment use this version as minimum

Comment: Thx for your help! Do you probably know an `apache jena` version which uses `java 1.6`?

Comment: Apache Jena 2.11.2 was the [last version to support java 6](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201408.mbox/%3C53DDF6B2.7030008@apache.org%3E). You just missed it :-)